# How to set the sublime default View to 2 rows

Tags: sublimetext3

Everytime I open sublime I do the following:

[image]

> Layout

then

> Rows: 2

Can I change a setting so that when I open sublime this is the default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no setting I'm aware of to control the layout of newly created windows; they're always created as a single file group. Probably the best/easiest thing to do would be to use the default key binding to set the layout you want, or bind it to another more easily accessible key, rather than going through the menu.

As has been mentioned in the comments on your question (with code possibly from [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1130426/221191)) it is possible to scratch this particular itch using Plugin code as well.

As presented in the linked answer and the comments above, the layout of the active window at Sublime start up will be switched into the two row layout.

This is sub-optimal since it will forcefully change the layout of the active window even if it already contains files (which may not be what you want), it only affects the active window even if there are many (which may not be what you want) and it doesn't affect windows created after the plugin was loaded (which is definitely not what you want).

A version that works around some of the limitations is below. Note however that on MacOS there are situations in which new windows are created that plugins are unable to detect, so depending on your operating system this still may not do what you want.

In the code below, the call to `plugin_loaded` finds all windows that currently exist and changes their layout, but only if they are currently using a single pane layout.

Additionally this also listens to see when a new window has been created at run time and also sets it's layout to be the desired default as well.

To use this, select `Tools > Developer > New Plugin` from the menu, replace the stub code with the following, then save it as a Python file in the folder Sublime will default to (your `User` package).

```python
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


def set_default_layout(window):
    """
    Change the layout of the provided window to the desired default.
    """
    window.run_command("set_layout",  {
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]],
        "cols": [0.0, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]})

    # Make sure the top group is given the focus
    window.focus_group(0)


def plugin_loaded():
    """
    Make all windows with a single file group have the default layout.
    """
    for window in sublime.windows():
        if window.num_groups() == 1:
            set_default_layout(window)


class DefaultPaneSetter(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    """
    Change the layout of newly created windows to be the default.
    """
    def on_post_window_command(self, window, command, args):
        if command == "new_window":
            set_default_layout(sublime.active_window())
```

As mentioned above, there are cases under MacOS where new windows are created without invoking the `new_window` command that the plugin is watching for, such as when you start up Sublime with no windows and it creates a default, or when you drag a new file to the dock to open it while you have `open_files_in_new_window` turned on.

As far as I'm aware there is no way to detect when that's happening short of constantly checking to see if there are more windows now than there were a few seconds ago, but that seems fairly intrusive and potentially performance draining.

Note also that if you're using any packages which in any way create new windows, this code may interfere with them by forcing the default layout onto the window when the package doesn't expect it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your version to 3.0 build 3143! I have this version and when I open it I have the last used layout (Row 2 if previously selected or other layout selected before the last Sublime closure).

Comment: I'm using that version but do not have the behaviour you describe

Comment: Anyhow, For more option in the default layout you can define your custom plugin. Go to `Preferences--> Browse Package` and define a new python code file with the following lines

Comment: `import sublime
def plugin_loaded():
    sublime.active_window().run_command("set_layout", {
        "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
        "rows": [0.0, 1.0],
        "cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]
    })`

Comment: save in the package folder opened from menu your <custom_file>.py with the above content

Comment: import sublime
    def plugin_loaded():
        sublime.active_window().run_command("set_layout", {"cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],"rows": [0.0, 1.0],"cells": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 1]]})

Comment: do i really need to do this via python - is there not a json file somewhere I can just manually amend?

Comment: you don't have nothing to know about python, you just have to copy the code, better reported and explained by OdatNurd, in a file with .py extention to see the new default layout applied. After that, you can play with the values inside cols, rows and cells to see your changes applied dynamically to your layout.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/side-by-side-view-from-command-line-mac/32660/5) (though with 2 columns instead of 2 rows) you can also achieve this via command line options instead of a plugin:

```
subl -n --command "set_layout {\"cells\": [[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2]], \"cols\": [0.0, 1.0], \"rows\": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0]}" file1 && subl --command "focus_group {\"group\": 1}" && subl file2
```